# Why can't I delete the file from a php script?

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, delete-file

Basically, I am proxying a file using a php script and then deleting it straight after... only, the file isn't deleting and I can't work out why.

This is a little out of context, so, happy to explain more should you need it.

```
exec("wget http://xxxx/123_" .$matches[1] . " --no-check-certificate -P /usr/share/nginx/www/" );

$file = "/usr/share/nginx/www/123_" . $matches[1];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exec("rm /usr/share/nginx/www/123_" . $matches[1] );

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `unlink($file);` if you still can't, try verifying the file's ownership and what uid php is using for you as well as the files permission.

Comment: @Hakre - Undoing your changes... If there is an easy error, please write in comments or as an answer, but, that isn't my script, so, someone may get the wrong idea or base an answer on that line e.t.c.

Comment: @Prix - never even heard of unlink before, so, no... reading up on it now... (FYI, this was my first PHP script... certainly no pro).

Comment: I would recommend you to stay away from system commands unless you really have no option within the language you are using. As for the question, have you check the later in my answer ? file ownership etc, also is the file being downloaded at all ? you can view the file ownership with `ls -la` on the shell. Try commenting the line that is supose to remove the file to make sure it's being downloaded.

Comment: @Prix - I know it isn't best practice, but, this server is only being used for this script, and everything is working fine with the exception of deletion... I would presume that it isn't a permission issue due to the rm being run from the script would be the same permission as the wget that created it... Anyway, I am trying to use unlink now and test.

Comment: For instance what if `rm` is not allowed with the user your are using or is asking for confirmation to delete the file ? You could try `rm -f file` if u do have access to it, some systems replace `rm` with an alias that does `rm -i` when its called and `-i` stands for interactive mode. So when you try to delete a file it will ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, which will not create a local file that needs to be deleted:

```
// Define URL
$url = "http://xxxx/123_{$matches[1]}";

// Open pointer to remote resource
if (!$remoteFP = @fopen($url, 'r')) {
  header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 500 Internal Server Error");
  exit;
}

// Get content length and type from remote server's headers
$length = $type = NULL;
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) { // Loop headers (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)
  list($name, $val) = explode(':', $header, 2); // Split to key/value
  switch (strtolower(trim($name))) { // See if it's a value we want
    case 'content-length':
      $length = (int) trim($val);
      break;
    case 'content-type':
      $type = trim($val);
      break;
  }
  if ($length !== NULL && $type !== NULL) break; // if we have found both we can stop looping
}

// Send headers
if ($type === NULL) $type = 'text/plain';
header("Content-Type: $type");
if ($length) header("Content-Length: $length"); // Only send content-length if the server sent one. You may want to do the same for content-type.

// Open a file pointer for the output buffer
$localFP = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// Send the data to the remote party
stream_copy_to_stream($remoteFP, $localFP);

// Close streams and exit
fclose($remoteFP);
fclose($localFP);
exit;
```

This uses the `fopen()` approach over cURL etc because it allows one to forward the entity straight to the output buffer, as well as giving access to the remote server's response headers before the body have been fully received. It is the most resource-efficient way to proxy using PHP.

If your server has `allow_url_fopen` disabled, you may be able to use cURL, which will also allow you to pass the data straight to the output buffer, but does not allow you to parse and forward the headers from the remote server.

Comment: I have given you +1 for the effort here and I am certainly learning a lot from it, however, the script I wrote has already gone to production and I would rather fix it if I can... The not deleting files was a bug that I missed. If I can't fix it quickly (just trying the unlink method at the moment), I will certainly try your version.

Comment: @Wil The code above should work for you out-of-the-box if you just drop it in place of the code you show in your question. The only thing you need to alter is the first line, to make sure the `$url` is correct. This version will also be considerably faster and more resource efficient than the `wget` approach, since it never writes data to disk, and starts sending the data the client immediately instead of transferring the whole file to your server before sending it on to the client.

Comment: sorry to sound dumb, but, is this script fully safe if run by more than one person at the same time... I am not an expert nor understand everything there, but, seeing the  `php://` bit is making me wonder what happens if someone else visits before the first one has finished to download... Sorry if this is idiotic, I just want to make sure.

Comment: Each concurrent request gets it's own instance of PHP, which is run independently of every other instance. There should be no concurrency issue with the above code - as long as the remote server doesn't have any (which is beyond the control of your script). The only time you might get a problem is if you are using sessions, and a single user tries to access the script with two concurrent requests. Even then, there is a simple solution, which is to call `session_write_close()` before the above code. But this only matters if you are using sessions.